# collecting excel data for gephi with Python

Tags: python

I have a data set that can be found here https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/pavansubhasht/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset.

What we need exactly is for every employee to have their own set of rows of all the employees they share the same age with.

The desired output would be to add these rows in the data frame like so

| source | target |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Tom |
| Bob | Carl |
| Tom | Bob |
| Tom | Carl |
| Carl | Bob |
| Carl | Tom |

I am using pandas to create the data frame from the csv file `pd.read_csv`
I am struggling with creating the loop to have my desired input.

This where I am at so far

```
import pandas as pd


path = "C:\CNT\IBM.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(path)

def f(row):
    if row['A'] == row['B']:
        val = 0
    elif row['A'] > row['B']:
        val = 1
    else:
        val = -1
    return val

df['source'] = ''
df['target'] = ''

df2 = (df.loc[df['Age'] == 18])
print(df2)
```

this produces this

```
      Age  EmployeeNumber  MonthlyIncome source target
296    18             297           1420              
301    18             302           1200              
457    18             458           1878              
727    18             728           1051              
828    18             829           1904              
972    18             973           1611              
1153   18            1154           1569              
1311   18            1312           1514
```

My desired output is this

```
       Age  EmployeeNumber  MonthlyIncome source target
296    18             297           1420    297    302      
301    18             302           1200    297    458      
457    18             458           1878    297    728      
727    18             728           1051    297    829      
828    18             829           1904    297    973      
972    18             973           1611    297    1154      
1153   18            1154           1569    297    1312     
1311   18            1312           1514
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Can you share your code you have so far?

Comment: I just added it as an edit

Comment: I would use `networkx` to construct and export the network.

Comment: DYZ can you show this in practice? keep in mind the total amount of nodes would be 1,470. Is it a viable option for such a large data set?

Answer (score 0):

This will need some modification because I don't have the features added that you do. But this copies the `EmployeeNumber` to a new column `target` and shifts the values up. Leaving the last `EmployeeNumber` as a `NaN`. I added some modification to have the last row in a group's target value empty. The line of code would need to be modified more if using strings in the source column as well. The main point is using `.shift(periods=-1)` with the `groupby()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = "C:\CNT\IBM.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path)

def f(row):
    val = np.where(row['A'] == row['B'], 0, np.where(row['A'] >= row['B'], 1, -1))
    return val

df['source'] = df['EmployeeNumber']
df['target'] = df.groupby('Age')['EmployeeNumber'].shift(periods=-1).fillna(0).astype(int).replace(0,'')
print(df)

df2 = (df.loc[df['Age'] == 18])
df3 = df2[['Age','EmployeeNumber','source','target']]
print(df3)
```